# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, ecmascript-6, karma-runner, webpack

Can you guys please help me fixing this issue.
I have two .jsx files one imported under another one.
Lets say,
A.jsx(Inside A.jsx I have imported the B.jsx)
B.jsx

When both the files are written under same file in that case unit test cases working fine. The moment I am separating it out, still the component is working fine but the unit test cases are not running. Webpack karma throwing an error saying

`ERROR in ./src/components/thpfooter/index.jsx Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./ThpFooterList in /Users/zi02/projects/creps_ui_components_library/src/components/thpfooter @ ./src/components/thpfooter/index.jsx 9:1725-1751`

## karma.conf.js

```
/*eslint-disable*/
var webpack = require('karma-webpack');
var argv = require('yargs').argv;
var componentName = "**";
if (typeof argv.comp !== 'undefined' && argv.comp !== null && argv.comp !== "" && argv.comp !== true) {
  componentName = argv.comp;
}

var testFiles = 'src/components/'+componentName+'/test/*.js';
var mockFiles = 'src/components/'+componentName+'/test/mock/*.json';

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      './node_modules/phantomjs-polyfill/bind-polyfill.js',
      testFiles,
      mockFiles
    ],
    plugins: [webpack,
              'karma-jasmine',
              'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
              'karma-coverage',
              'karma-spec-reporter',
              'karma-json-fixtures-preprocessor',
              'karma-junit-reporter'],
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    preprocessors: {
      'src/components/**/test/*.js': ['webpack'],
      'src/components/**/*.jsx': ['webpack'],
      'src/components/**/test/mock/*.json': ['json_fixtures']
    },
    jsonFixturesPreprocessor: {
      // strip this from the file path \ fixture name
      stripPrefix: 'src/components/',
      // strip this to the file path \ fixture name
      prependPrefix: '',
      // change the global fixtures variable name
      variableName: '__mocks__',
     // camelize fixture filenames
     // (e.g 'fixtures/aa-bb_cc.json' becames __fixtures__['fixtures/aaBbCc'])
      camelizeFilenames: true,
      // transform the filename
      transformPath: function (path) {
        return path + '.js';
      }
    },
    reporters: ['spec', 'coverage','junit'],
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: 'build/reports/coverage',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html', subdir: 'report-html' },
        { type: 'lcov', subdir: 'report-lcov' }
      ]
    },
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'build/reports/coverage/junit/'+componentName,
      suite: ''
    },

    webpack: {
      module: {
        loaders: [{
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }],
        postLoaders: [{
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, exclude: /(node_modules|test)/,
          loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter'
        }]
      }
    },
    webpackMiddleware: { noInfo: true }
  });
};
```

## footer.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ThpFooterList from './ThpFooterList';

class ThpFooter extends React.Component {
   //footer code here
}
```

## ThpFooterList.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

class ThpFooterList extends React.Component {
   //footer list code here
}
```

See above component is working but I am not able to execute the unit test case. When you keep both of them in one file means footer and footerlist.jsx then component as well as the unit test cases are executing.

## unit test case file

```
/* eslint-env jasmine */
import React from 'react';
import TestUtils from 'react/lib/ReactTestUtils';

import ThpFooter from '../index.jsx';


describe('ThpFooter', () => {
  let component;
  let content;
  let shallowRenderer;
  let componentShallow;

  beforeAll(() => {
    content = window.__mocks__['thpfooter/test/mock/content'];
    component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<ThpFooter data={content}/>);
    shallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
    shallowRenderer.render(<ThpFooter data={content}/>);
    componentShallow = shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();
  });

  describe('into DOM', () => {
    it('Should be rendered into DOM', () => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('Should have classname as footer-container', () => {
      const classname = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass(component, 'footer-container');
      expect(classname[0].className).toBe('footer-container');
    });

    it('Should have className as footer-wrapper', () => {
      const classname = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass(component, 'footer-wrapper');
      expect(classname[0].className).toBe('footer-wrapper');
    });
  });

  describe('into shallow renderer', () => {
    it('Should be rendered as shallow renderer', () => {
      expect(componentShallow).toBeTruthy();

    });

    it('Should have classname as footer-container', () => {
      expect(componentShallow.props.className).toBe('footer-container');
    });

    it('Should have className as footer-wrapper', () => {
      expect(componentShallow.props.children.props.children[0].props.className).toBe('footer-wrapper');
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: code, code, code. Post your code when requesting for help

Comment: @Andreyco: please find the updated question. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error on one of the development machines. Although gulp and webpack-stream was used in my case, I think you may reference my method to try solving it.

On my mac, everything is fine but when I pushed the code to the ubuntu development platform, this problem was observed. After some googling I cannot solve it but then I tried to make the file path to be shorter and then suddenly it works on the ubuntu development platform too! You may try to shorten the file name or place it in a shorter path and test to see if it works.

Comment: My file path is shorter and strange thing is that the component is working but only the unit test cases are failing. Even I am using a mac machine to develop. :)

Comment: I found that my problem was that file system on mac is case insensitive but that of linux system is case sensitive. I guess the problem is in the line `import ThpFooter from '../index.jsx';` and the file cannot be resolved from that index.jsx file

Comment: its not due to case insensitive @redcomethk

Comment: The problem for my case is that the git config on my development machine is case insensitive, so that it did not watch when I changed the file name from lowercase to uppercase and thus the file was not pushed to the staging machine...

Answer (score 0):

Watch for case sensitivity. Mac file system is not case-sensitive, windows/linux is.